# Mac OSX modifying keyboard shortcuts - different methods

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

There are 2 ways to make F2 button rename files in OSX

1. in file ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict, insert this:

   "\UF705"  = "rename:";
2. run this command:
   defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add
   'Rename' '\UF705'

Which method is better?
What happens if there are conflicting shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultKeyBinding.dict` is ignored by many applications like XCode and Firefox. Even in an application where `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` is not ignored, the `rename:` method might not work for renaming files or other items.

Running `defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Rename' '\UF705'` modifies `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`, but you have to quit and reopen Finder to apply the changes. It does the same thing as adding a shortcut for the "Rename" menu item under Finder from "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts". You can add a global shortcut that does not apply to only Finder by running `defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add Rename \\Uf705` or by adding the shortcut under "All Applications" from System Preferences.

If an application has a menu item whose shortcut is F2, it has precedence over the shortcut defined in `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, but it is overridden by the shortcut defined in `NSUserKeyEquivalents`.

iTunes does not have a menu item called "Rename", and the `rename:` method does not work for renaming a playlist item in iTunes, so neither method works in iTunes.

It will probably be more convenient to just use the OS X standard shortcut to rename items, which is usually return, or enter (fn + return) in places like iTunes playlists.